# Apply regular expression to the second word in "|" separated string in a interpretor Flume config

Tags: regex, hadoop, interceptor, flume

My requirement is to apply regular expression to the data coming from kafka.

The data is as follow:

```
abc|def|mnq|xyz
abc1|def1|mnq1|xyz1
abc2|def2|mnq2|xyz2
```

I want to apply regular expression on the second word i.e (def) from the first sting using a flume interpretor.

Regular expression can be to filter words and decimal numbers.

Can someone help in this.

Comment: Try "\w+:(.*?):\w+" to match every second word in all lines. Try "abc:(.*?):mnq" only to match the second word in the first line. I am not aware of Flume, so the given regular expressions are generic.

Comment: Thanks naveen for the reply.... But it dint work

Comment: do you want to retrieve only the second word in the first line or all second words from all the lines?

Comment: All the lines....

Comment: Ok, I tried "\w+:(.*?):\w+" in notepad++, which is working for me. May i know what is regular expression style does Flume uses? like Perl, Python, Java etc?

Comment: Python or java should work

Comment: "\w+:(.*?):\w+" is matching only first line or no matches at all?

Comment: Not matching any...

Comment: And the data is separated by | and not :

Comment: would you please share the piece of code which is responsible for regex matching

Comment: agent.sources.avro-AppSrv-source1.interceptors.i1.regex = \w+|(.*?)|\w+

Comment: posted answer, try and let me know. the trick is you need to escape "|", which is a special character by using "\"

Comment: tried...but not working

Comment: try try  "\\w+\|(.*?)\|\\w+"

Comment: from example, https://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.3.0/apidocs/org/apache/flume/interceptor/RegexExtractorInterceptor.html

Comment: try "\\w+\|(\\w+)\|\\w+"

Comment: also try  "\\w\|(\\w)\|\\w"

Comment: No ya its not working

Answer (score 1):

Following python code matches all the second words in all the lines:

```
import re

# used || to add multilines combine into one string
parent = """abc|def|mnq|xyz||
abc1|def1|mnq1|xyz1||
abc2|def2|mnq2|xyz2"""

pattern = re.compile("\w+\|(.*?)\|\w+", re.MULTILINE)
m = pattern.findall(parent)
print m
```

which outputs|

```
['def', 'def1', 'def2']
```

**Note:** escape '|' by '\'.